# How can I save an Excel sheet as a PDF to two different locations at once?

Tags: excel, vba, save, export-to-pdf

I am trying to get this VBA macro to save the selection from an Excel sheet as a PDF but in two different locations. The reason is part of the company seems to use OneDrive as their default directory and the other uses their local drive. So when I have the export as C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop, it will do that, but it won't appear on Desktops of those who use OneDrive. So I figured I'd code it up to where it saves in both directories so no matter what they use, it's on their actual Desktop. However, when I get to the second save location, it triggers the following error: **Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error**

```
  Sub gpSaveSend()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String, signature As String
  Dim PdfFile2 As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim RngCopied As Range
  Dim StrName As String
  Dim strCheck As String
  Dim strCheck2 As String
  Dim StrPath As String
  Dim StrPath2 As String
  Dim StrFullPath As String
  Dim StrFullPath2 As String

  Set RngCopied = Selection
 
    Title = Range("A1")
    MyDate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    With ThisWorkbook
    StrPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive - xxx \" & "Desktop\"
    StrName = ActiveSheet.Range("AA40")
    StrName2 = ActiveSheet.Range("AA34")
    StrName3 = ActiveSheet.Range("AA33")
    StrName4 = ActiveSheet.Range("AA38")
    PdfFile = StrPath & ActiveSheet.Range("AA40") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA34") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & "\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & " - " & MyDate & ".pdf"
    PdfFile2 = StrPath2 & ActiveSheet.Range("AA40") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA34") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & "\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & " - " & MyDate & ".pdf"
    StrFullPath = StrPath & "\" & StrName & "\" & PdfFile
    StrFullPath2 = StrPath2 & "\" & StrName & "\" & PdfFile2
    strCheck = StrPath & "\" & StrName
    FolderCheck (strCheck)
    strCheck = strCheck & "\" & StrName2
    FolderCheck (strCheck)
    strCheck = strCheck & "\" & StrName3
    FolderCheck (strCheck)
    strCheck = strCheck & "\" & Year(Date)
    YearFolderCheck (strCheck)
    strCheck = strCheck & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm")
    YearFolderCheck (strCheck)
    strCheck = strCheck & "\" & StrName4
    YearFolderCheck (strCheck)

    End With
  
  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .Zoom = False
  End With
  
    Sheets("Form").Range("A1:K91").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


    With ThisWorkbook

    StrPath2 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    PdfFile2 = StrPath2 & ActiveSheet.Range("AA40") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA34") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & "\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & " - " & MyDate & ".pdf"
    StrFullPath2 = StrPath2 & "\" & StrName & "\" & PdfFile2
    strCheck2 = StrPath2 & "\" & StrName
    FolderCheck2 (strCheck2)
    strCheck2 = strCheck2 & "\" & StrName2
    FolderCheck2 (strCheck2)
    strCheck2 = strCheck2 & "\" & StrName3
    FolderCheck2 (strCheck2)
    strCheck2 = strCheck2 & "\" & Year(Date)
    YearFolderCheck2 (strCheck2)
    strCheck2 = strCheck2 & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm")
    YearFolderCheck2 (strCheck2)
    strCheck2 = strCheck2 & "\" & StrName4
    YearFolderCheck2 (strCheck2)

    End With
  
  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .Zoom = False
  End With


    Sheets("Form").Range("A1:K91").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile2, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


    
    
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)
   
    .Display
    .Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("AA38") & " Completed - " & ActiveSheet.Range("AA33") & " - " & MyDate
    .CC = "xxxx@xxx.com"
    .HTMLBody = "<pre><BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & Sheets("Form").Range("AA2").Value & "<a href=""mailto: Enter Your Lead's Email Here?cc=xxxx@xxx.com&subject=Coaching Acknowledgement&body=Hello, xxxxxxx:%0d%0d"">**Click Here to Acknowledge**</a>" & "</body></pre>" & _
    .HTMLBody      ' Adds default outlook account signature
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile
   
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
   
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
    ' MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 
  End With
    
  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit
 
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function FolderCheck(strCheck As String)

Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FolderExists(strCheck)) Then
    Exit Function
Else

    fso.createfolder (strCheck)
End If

End Function

Function FolderCheck2(strCheck2 As String)

Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FolderExists(strCheck2)) Then
    Exit Function
Else

    fso.createfolder (strCheck2)
End If

End Function

Function YearFolderCheck(strCheck As String)

Dim fso As Object
Dim strFiller As String

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FolderExists(strCheck)) Then
        Exit Function
    Else

        fso.createfolder (strCheck)
        Exit Function
    End If


End Function
Function YearFolderCheck2(strCheck2 As String)

Dim fso As Object
Dim strFiller As String

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FolderExists(strCheck2)) Then
        Exit Function
    Else

        fso.createfolder (strCheck2)
        Exit Function
    End If


End Function

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
 
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
 
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
 
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
 
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
 
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
 
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
 
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile2, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Specifically, it gets snagged at the above "PdfFile2" export code, which the only difference is the starting path, everything else is the same. It doesn't matter which path I use, if I swap the two, only the first export works and the second one won't. I'm not sure what to do or if there is a better solution to care for the issue.

**UPDATE: I updated the code in my workbook and above to pretty much create two separate instances of exporting the file to include dedicated Strings, and it seems to make it through but now triggers Run-time error '76', Path not found, which then highlights the fso.createfolder line**

`fso.createfolder (strCheck2)`

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try reselecting the range again before the second export?

Comment: I actually originally had the Range selection there for the second one and removed it in case that was the problem. Still happened either way. Good thought, though!

Comment: Qualify the range and export that, instead of selection?

Comment: I updated it as: Sheets("Form").Range("A1:K91").ExportAsFixedFormat and the first one exported fine but the second still did not, same error and same place.

Comment: You have ````` at the end of the second one?

Comment: filecopy? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143201/excel-vba-copy-file-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my question, that was me failing at embedding code in the text editor lol. There is no ```` at the end of the actual code.

Comment: I can't replicate.

Comment: I just realized I didn't have StrPath2 defined as String but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Why don't you share the code from `Sub` to `End Sub`. Whatever you're trying to do with `FolderCheck` seems wrong or useless. Why don't you share its code? Sharing the contents of the `AA` cells might also help. Please explain what the `ActiveWorkbook` is and why you are saving it. Please share the tab name of the `ActiveSheet` in (hopefully) `ThisWorbook`. The only `ActiveSheet` should be used for the worksheet containing the export range but even there it is covered by `Selection`. Best add the additional information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72664961/edit).

Comment: I just updated the post to add the entire module as well as another error I'm getting. I started to get a little messy so if it looks horrible, apologies in advance. The AA cells contain text like names or subjects. ActiveWorkbook.Save is there to save the workbook as in the past users have forgotten to do so and lost their work, so it's a guardrail for them. ActiveSheet is named "Form"